# Regular Expression Match (get multiple stuff in a group)

Tags: regex

I have trouble working on this regular expression.

Here is the string in one line, and I want to be able to extract the thing in the `swatchColorList`, specifically I want the word `Natural Burlap`, `Navy`, `Red`

What I have tried is '[(.*?)]' to get everything inside bracket, but what I really want is to do it in one line? is it possible, or do I need to do this in two steps?

Thanks

```
     {"id":"1349306","categoryName":"Kids","imageSource":"7/optimized/8769127_fpx.tif","swatchColorList":[{"Natural Burlap":"8/optimized/8769128_fpx.tif"},{"Navy":"5/optimized/8748315_fpx.tif"},{"Red":"8/optimized/8748318_fpx.tif"}],"suppressColorSwatches":false,"primaryColor":"Natural Burlap","clickableSwatch":true,"selectedColorNameID":"Natural Burlap","moreColors":false,"suppressProductAttribute":false,"colorFamily":{"Natural Burlap":"Ivory/Cream"},"maxQuantity":6}
```

Comment: What language are you using? This cannot be parsed with a regular expression and should be parsed using a JSON serializer.

Comment: lets say python. But I really want to use regular expression on this problem. =)

Comment: Why use regex when you have (what looks like) valid JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
(?<=[[,]\{\")[^"]+
```

[image]

If negative lookbehind is not supported, you can use

```
[[,]\{"([^"]+)
```

This will save needed word in group 1.

Comment: I see, but it only works for "Natural Burlap", unable to get the rest result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

str = '{"id":"1349306","categoryName":"Kids","imageSource":"7/optimized/8769127_fpx.tif","swatchColorList":[{"Natural Burlap":"8/optimized/8769128_fpx.tif"},{"Navy":"5/optimized/8748315_fpx.tif"},{"Red":"8/optimized/8748318_fpx.tif"}],"suppressColorSwatches":false,"primaryColor":"Natural Burlap","clickableSwatch":true,"selectedColorNameID":"Natural Burlap","moreColors":false,"suppressProductAttribute":false,"colorFamily":{"Natural Burlap":"Ivory/Cream"},"maxQuantity":6}'
obj = json.loads(str)
words = []
for thing in obj["swatchColorList"]:
    for word in thing:
        words.append(word)
        print word
```

Output will be

```
Natural Burlap
Navy
Red
```

And words will be stored to `words` list. I realize this is not a regex but I want to discourage the use of regex on serialized object notations as regular expressions are not intended for the purpose of parsing strings with nested expressions.